# Recursive call in Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have a project with Camel and my route has a recursive call to itself in order to implement logic "call stored procedure while it returns a data set":

```
<route id="trxnReader">
    <from uri="direct:query"/>

    <to uri="sql-stored:classpath:sql/getTrxnsProcedure.sql?dataSource=myDataSource"
        id="storedprocGetTrxns"/>

    <choice>
        <when>
            <simple>${body} != null</simple>

            <split>
                <simple>${body.transactions}</simple>
                <filter>
                    <method ref="trnxFilter" method="filter"/>
                    <to uri="direct:processTrxn"/>
                </filter>
            </split>

            <to uri="direct:query"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <log id="failUploadInfo" message="Transactions don't exist" loggingLevel="INFO"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</route>
```

The problem with this code is that if my stored procedure constantly returns something for a long time not allowing to exit the recursion, I get `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. I need something like loop. What is the best way to implement such logic with Camel? I'm using Camel 2.15.3.

Comment: Perhaps go to `<to uri="direct:query"/>` asynchronously?

Comment: `I need something like loop.` E.g. [Loop](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/loop-eip.html#_using_while_mode)?

Comment: There is Loop EIp as Bedla mentions

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use Loop EIP because I don't have a predefined number of iterations, and "loopDoWhile" doesn't exist in Camel 2.15.3.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround with custom bean and loop exit condition (`isLoopDone` property)

```
public class LoopBean {

    @Handler
    public void loop(@ExchangeProperty("loopEndpoint") String endpoint, Exchange exchange) {
        ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
        boolean isLoopDone = false;
        Exchange currentExchange = exchange;

        do {
            currentExchange = producerTemplate.send(endpoint, currentExchange);
            Object isLoopDoneProperty = currentExchange.getProperty("isLoopDone");
            if (isLoopDoneProperty != null) {
                isLoopDone = (boolean) isLoopDoneProperty;
            }
        }
        while (!isLoopDone);
    }
}
```

```
<route id="trxnReader">
    <from uri="direct:query"/>
    <setProperty propertyName="loopEndpoint">
        <simple>direct:callStoredProcWhileItHasTransactions</simple>
    </setProperty>

    <bean ref="loopBean"/>
</route>

<route id="storedProcCallingLoop">
    <from uri="direct:callStoredProcWhileItHasTransactions"/>

    <to uri="sql-stored:classpath:sql/getTrxnsProcedure.sql?dataSource=myDataSource"
        id="storedprocGetTrxns"/>

    <choice>
        <when>
            <simple>${body} != null</simple>

            <split>
                <simple>${body.transactions}</simple>
                <filter>
                    <method ref="trnxFilter" method="filter"/>
                    <to uri="direct:processTrxn"/>
                </filter>
            </split>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <log id="failUploadInfo" message="Transactions don't exist" loggingLevel="INFO"/>
            <setProperty propertyName="isLoopDone">
                <simple resultType="java.lang.Boolean">true</simple>
            </setProperty>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</route>
```